# Ruby regex how to replace each item after a lookback?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm struggling a bit with replacing some spaces with HTML nbsp; characters.
I'm trying to replace each space with a nbsp; character (not replace all of them with one nbsp;).

Here's what I'm trying at the moment:

```
 "My String:         ".gsub(/(?<=:).*\s/, '&nbsp;')
 =>"My String:&nbsp;"
```

but this is about as close that I can get (I can kinda see why it's not working, but I'm unable to take it to that next step - if there is one?)...

Any Regex gods out there that can help?

Comment: each, but not all of them? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I mean if I have 5 spaces, I want 5 dashes, and not 1 dash to represent the 5 spaces. I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with your regexp you could just go:

```
p "My String:         ".gsub(/(?<=:).*\s/){|x| '&nbsp;'*x.size }
#=> "My String:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
```

If you instead want to make a new regexp:

```
# Any single space character that must be followed by 0+ spaces and then end of string.
string.gsub(/\s(?=\s*\Z)/,'&nbsp;')
```

Comment: Thanks Hirolau! works a charm - I didn't know you could pass gsub a block like you've done for the first example. I think the second one is a lot cleaner though. Cheers :)